# How do i pass props in react router component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm quite new to react and trying to understand how to pass props.

1st i have set a Navlink component which holds a subcategories property :

```
<NavLink
  catid={category.id}
  to={category.route}
  catname={category.name}
  subcategories={category.subcategories}
>
  {category.name}
</NavLink>
```

`{category.route}`, `{category.name}`, `{category.subcategories}` are fetched from json file, so this part is OK.

Each route is defined so:

```
<Route
  path='/epicerie-sucree'
  render={(props) => (
    <CategoryPage
      {...props}
      catid={10}
      catname={"Epicerie sucrée"}
      subcategories={props.subcategories}
    />
  )}
/>
```

so it renders a component named `<CategoryPage/>`

And here's the code of the CategoryPage Component :

```
export default function CategoryPage(props) {  
  return (
    <div>
      {  props.subcategories.map(subcat => (
            <div>{subcat.subcat_name}</div>
      ))}
      <FooterCat cat={catData.categories}></FooterCat>
    </div>) 
}
```

So the categoryPage component should receive correctly the props transmitted through the router, no ?

Instead it throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" I don't understand...
Thanks

Comment: you should pass the props as url parameters and define the urls accordingly

Comment: It would be good if you add json file content in same structure.

Comment: @Sameer Reza Khan. Here it is https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5ea1636098b3d53752331597

Answer (score 2):

`NavLink` won't pass props to the component being rendered by the route, but what you can do is to pass some "state" with the route push that occurs. The `render` prop passes the [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) to the component and you spread that to the `CategoryPage` component.

```
<NavLink
  to={{
    pathname: category.route,
    state: {
      catid: { category.id },
      catname: { category.name },
      subcategories: { category.subcategories },
    }
  }}
>
  {category.name}
</NavLink>
```

Now the state will be passed with the route push on the [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) prop.

```
props.location.state.subcategories
```

Component

```
export default function CategoryPage(props) {  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        props.location.state.subcategories.map(subcat => (
          <div>{subcat.subcat_name}</div>
      ))}
      <FooterCat cat={catData.categories}></FooterCat>
    </div>) 
}
```

*May need to do the same for `catData.categories` as it isn't clear what that is*